# not update list when delete element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

i write this code for delete comment . but when i delete comment it remove from database but not remove in page ( View ) so i need to refresh that , in this case remove from page . how can i solve this problem ?

```
function DeleteNews(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/admin/news/deletenews/" + id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === true) {
                alert("خبر با موفقیت حذف گردید");
            } else {
                alert("حذف نشد  . خطایی رخ داده");
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

View

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>کد خبر</th>
            <th>عنوان خبر</th>
            <th>عملیات</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ListNews)
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="news(@item.NewsID)">@item.NewsID</td>
                <td>@item.NewsTitle</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("/EditNews/",new { NewsID=item.NewsID})" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">ویرایش</a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="DetailNews(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        جزئیات
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="NewsComment(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        نظرات
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="DetailNews(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        فایل های مریوطه
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="DeleteNews(@item.NewsID)">حذف</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to remove the associated elements from the DOM in the success callback. You need to show the code in the view.

Comment: After delete just send fresh data to bind as AjaxResult or Redirect to news list page.

Comment: @Amit how do this ? please write that code

Comment: @StephenMuecke i edit question

Comment: @Kianoush, Amits suggestion is to essentially refresh the whole view which is not what you want.

Comment: Use a framework such as Knockout or Angular they can handle View updates with data bindings

Answer (score 0):

```
=== // It's a strong comparison


function DeleteNews(id) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/admin/news/deletenews/" + id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) { // Just it
                // And here is select your comment element and remove him
                $('#comment-' + id).remove();
                alert("Comment removed");
            } else {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
function DeleteNews(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/admin/news/deletenews/" + id,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    alert("data deleted");
                    //below are the different ways to remove the element
                    $('#post-id-'+id).remove(); // removes the element itself leaving others untouched
                    $('#post-id-'+id).empty();// keeps the element but removes all children
                    $('#post-id-'+id).closest("#parent_id").empty(); // travels up the DOM searching for the first parent with the class/id and empties it keeping the parent itself
                    $('#post-id-'+id).closest("#parent_id").remove();// travels up the DOM searching for the first parent and removes it and all its children
                    $('#post-id-'+id).html(' //my new html code here'); // can be used to show that the post has been deleted without showing an alert, much like Facebook does when you unfollow a friend, can also be ("") to empty it
                } else {
                    alert("حذف نشد  . خطایی رخ داده");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

modify your html code a bit like so

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>کد خبر</th>
            <th>عنوان خبر</th>
            <th>عملیات</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ListNews)
        {
            <tr id="post-id-news(@item.NewsID)"">
                <td id="news(@item.NewsID)">@item.NewsID</td>
                <td>@item.NewsTitle</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("/EditNews/",new { NewsID=item.NewsID})" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">ویرایش</a>
                    <button type="button" onclick="DetailNews(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        جزئیات
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="NewsComment(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        نظرات
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="DetailNews(@item.NewsID)" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        فایل های مریوطه
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="DeleteNews(@item.NewsID)">حذف</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Kianoush - This is just a logic. I believe you need to fit correct element Id  or parent id in this.

Comment: @Kianoush do you get any errors when you click the delete button?

Comment: then check the id for both the `<tr>` and the `<button>`, both should have same numbers